# Multiselect Combo box in EXT JS

Tags: extjs

I want multiselect combo box example through EXT JS. Could you please give some sample coding which I can implement in Grid also....

Answer (score 2):

Nice one here: http://www.tonylandis.com/code-projects/ext-multiselect-combobox-extension.htm
Not sure it works for Extjs 3.X.

There's also this one http://www.technomedia.co.uk/SuperBoxSelect/examples3.html , not so nice but 3.X compatible…