# Multiselect combobox with ExtJs

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs, multi-select

How do you implement a multiselect combobox as part of a `Ext.FormPanel` using ExtJs?  I've been looking, but can't seem to find a solution that is compatible with the latest version of ExtJs ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635809/multiselect-combo-box-in-ext-js) is similar, but doesn't have a working/current solution).

This is what I have so far, but it's a single select:

```
new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelAlign: 'top',
    frame:      true,
    width:      800,
    items: [{
        layout: 'column',
        items:[{
            columnWidth: 1,
            layout:      'form',
            items: [{
                xtype:          'combo',
                fieldLabel:     'Countries',
                name:           'c[]',
                anchor:         '95%',
                allowBlank:     false,
                typeAhead:      true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                lazyRender:     true,
                mode:           'local',
                store:          new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                    id:     0,
                    fields: ['myId', 'displayText'],
                    data: [
                        ["CA", 'Canada'], 
                        ["US", 'United States'],
                        ["JP", 'Japan'],
                    ]
                }),
                valueField:   'myId',
                displayField: 'displayText'
            }]
        }]
    }]
}).render(document.body);
```

I didn't see any parameters in the [documentation](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox) that suggests that this is supported. I also found [this](http://www.figtreesystems.com/ext/ext-ux/2.0/Multiselect/Multiselect.html) and [this](http://tonylandis.com/code/ext-multiselect-combobox-extension/) but I could only get them working with Ext 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [SuperBoxSelect](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?69307-3.x-Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect) extension.

Comment: I actually found that one earlier, but the examples weren't loading for some reason so I wrote it off. Turns out that it was exactly what I needed.  Thanks man.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the box's height? There are a lot of countries and it makes the box that shows the selected values very tall.

Comment: I see that there is a `maxHeight` property, but this applies to the list of possible values, not the list of chosen values, which is the one that I want to restrict.

Comment: Nevermind that stupid follow up question. I realized after I asked this that I can achieve what I need with css.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Saki's [Ext.ux.form.LovCombo](http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/)

Comment: It looks like it would work, but I like the UI of superboxselect better.

Comment: Did anybody try pre-selecting a few checkboxes in the dropdown on load? A team member of mine is facing some issues with it.