# Javascript ComboBox - does a name for or example of this particular feature exist?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I've made an extended ComboBox based on the one ExtJs features.

That's all fine. Now I'm looking to implement this one particular feature, and I'm trying to find out if anyone has done it before me, so I could look over his or her shoulder :)

The feature is, that when an item in the list is selected, the text is returned to the text field "as a whole" or "in a bubble" ... just like when you select an e-mail-address in Outlook. It is inserted as a whole, and if you backspace after the text is inserted, you will delete the entire text.

It may be obvious that my problem is, that I can't figure out what such a feature might be called or how it is best described and therefore I can not find any samples or descriptions anywhere. I just have a feeling that I've seen it somewhere.

If anyone has a clue what I'm rambling about and in addition knows good search terms or samples for it, I will be very delighted :)

Comment: Like a tag set.  I don't know what it's called, though.

Comment: Ha, found it. FogBugz features a javascript version of this. So now at least I know it can be done. But still good samples or names for this are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a [MultiSelect ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979989/multiselect-combobox-with-extjs).